# form segmentation value 'each' loop ajax request

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have a html form to get information from users. I segment this information to launch from each segment an ajax request (the segmentation is done following ">" characters). However, when I did not use 'each' jquery function (so without segmentation) ajax works, but with each jquery function ajax does not work at all and the loop does not work.

This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#formu').on('submit', function() {
            var sequence = $('#sequence').val().split(">"); // I segment here
            $.each(sequence, function(k){ // for each segment I launch a request with the segment as argument
                if (sequence[k].length != 0){
                    alert(sequence[k]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'run.py',
                        type:$(this).attr('method'),
                        data: {'sequence':">"+sequence[k]}, // the segment is given to python script
                        success: function(data){
                                               $('#result').html(data);
                                                }

                    });
                } // enf if
                //return false; 

            }); // end of each
        }); // end of submit
    }); // end of jquery
```

This is my html:

MyPage

```
<form method="post" id="formu" >
<textarea id="sequence" name="sequence" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

example of input:

```
>mysequence 1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>mysequence 2
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>mysequence 3
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop through an array using [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). You get passed key, value pairs into the function. What you were doing was getting the value back from the key, while it is already passed. There is no need to do that. Also, instead of returning `false` you can also prevent the event from doing its default behaviour

```
$('#formu').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior

    var sequence = $('#sequence').val();
    alert(sequence); // Check this value

    sequence = sequence.split(">");

    $.each(sequence, function(key, value){ 
        alert(value); // Alert is better placed here so you know what 'value' is

        if (value.length != 0){

            $.ajax({
                url     : 'run.py',
                type    : $("#formo").attr('method'), // Replaced 'this' with your form as 'this' might mean something you are not expecting here
                data    : { 'sequence' : ">"+value },
                success : function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                }
            });
         }
    });
});
```

As we don't know about you getting errors it is hard to do more than 'general improvements' to your code.

I think the reason it does not work might be because you use `this` in a `$.each` loop which might refer to the string instead of the form.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thank you so much!! This is really perfect and what I was looking for! I will do carefully about the 'this' in the future.

Comment: Just a little comment. It works but apparently at each iteration the previous result disappear event with $('#result').html('').append("<div>"+data+"</div><br>"); Is there a way to keep on the page all iterations?

Comment: Remove the `.html('')` from that line you just commented and you should be fine (it sets the HTML to ''). Perhaps reset the html just once before the loop? BTW, you don't need to place a `<br>` after a `<div>` unless you changed the CSS.